# Closing a running program via bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, kill, gnu-screen

I've tried searching for this a few times, but I just think I don't know the right terminology.

I have an application running in a screen session on a remote server. I'm periodically developing and updating the server, and use a Git repo to transfer my code. I'd like to automate this process. Here's what I want the script to do:

- Commit my code to my local machine repository
- Push the local repository to the server
- SSH to the server
- Atttach to the screen, and *kill* the application that is currently running there.

  - When I do this whole thing manually, I kill it with ctrl-C. That doesn't appear to be an option here.
- Then restart it using the new code.

Any thoughts on how to kill the application? Or a better way overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script needs to get the PID of the process and kill it. You can use

```
ps -u <process-owning name> | grep <process name>
```

to get info about the process. Use other stuff to extract the PID then do a kill on that.

I used something like this to kill the daily Quake 3 server through Cygwin on Windows.

Comment: `pgrep $PROCESS_NAME` returns the PID. Just do a `kill $(pgrep $PROCESS_NAME)`. Or a `kill -9` if the bare kill is not powerful enough :)

Comment: I think kill \`pgrep $PROCESS_NAME\` is what you're looking for in a bash script. The backticks mean to execute the command, turn the result into a string and continue processing the command line.

Comment: backticks and $()  are functionally the same.